# Can "humanology" be protected?

Tags: trademark

I wanted to buy a new domain, humanology.com, but discovered it's already taken. It looks like humanology.org is taken, too. Moreover, the webmaster of humanology.com claims he has trademarked the word "humanology," which cannot be used on other books or websites in reference to the study of humans.

However, I believe there are at least three books with "Humanology" in thir title. I'm not sure if the author of Humanology: A Scientist's Guide to our Amazing Existence is the same guy who owns humanology.com.

The National Library of Medicine promotes a Text Book of Humanology, which is supposedly in the public domain -- https://collections.nlm.nih.gov/catalog/nlm:nlmuid-00830010R-bk

I thought humanology was listed in the dictionary, but I was apparently wrong, though it has been submitted as a new world proposal -- https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/submission/405409/Humanology

When I searched for "humanology" at uspto.gov, I couldn't find anything related to humanology.com. However, I did find the following:

> Goods & services
>
> IC 041: Providing online publications of specialized electronic books...
>
> outbound
>
> Class
>
> 041, 045
>
> Serial
>
> 79260380
>
> Owners
>
> Jessica J. Lockhart (INDIVIDUAL; SPAIN)

So, it looks like publishing a book titled Humanology would be illegal, though I should be able to create a website with that name, right?

Comment: Trademarks for common words generally have very limited scope. This is how Apple Records and Apple Computers can both trademark "Apple" -- one is limited to the music industry, the other to the computer industry (there was an early trademark dispute, which was settled when Apple Computers agreed to stay out of music publishing).

Comment: So unless you're in the book publishing business and try to use Humanology as a brand name, I don't think the above trademark is likely to impact you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trademarks identify a *source* of goods or services. Titles of individual books are not trademarked but the name of book publishers are trademarked as are the names of a series of books. You can publish a book titled Humanology, but can't create books from or by Humanology. You can learn more from [this](https://www.uspto.gov/trademarks/laws/title-single-work-refusal-and-how-overcome-refusal) USPTO resource.

Also, being in the dictionary is not a bar to a trademark - Windows, Apple, Amazon, Craftsman, etc. are all in the dictionary.